# Detecting when a user taps a SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch, skspritenode

I'm new to swift programming and I decided I would make a simple game to start with SpriteKit. I have a SpriteNode that is supposed to pick 1 of 6 locations and move there when it is tapped, however from the methods I've seen I can't figure out how to implement it (again I'm new at this) Here is my code from the GameScene.swift file:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let greenTileWidth = screenSize.width * 0.5
    let greenTileHeight = screenSize.height * 0.33
    let greenTilePositionY = [greenTileHeight / 2, greenTileHeight / 2 + greenTileHeight, greenTileHeight / 2 + greenTileHeight * 2 ]
    let greenTilePositionX = [greenTileWidth / 2, greenTileWidth / 2 + greenTileWidth]

    let backgroundTile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "whiteTile")
    backgroundTile.size.width = screenSize.width * 100
    backgroundTile.size.height = screenSize.height * 100
    addChild(backgroundTile)

    let greenTile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenTile")
    greenTile.size.width = greenTileWidth
    greenTile.size.height = greenTileHeight
    greenTile.position.y = greenTilePositionY[0]
    greenTile.position.x = greenTilePositionX[0]
    greenTile.userInteractionEnabled = true
    addChild(greenTile)

    var randomX:Int = 0
    var randomY:Int = 0


    func getRandomY() -> Int{
        randomY = Int(arc4random_uniform(26))%3
        return randomY
    }

    func getRandomX() -> Int{
        randomX = Int(arc4random_uniform(26))%2
        return randomX
    }

    func moveGreenTile(){
        greenTile.position.x = greenTilePositionX[randomX]
        greenTile.position.y = greenTilePositionY[randomY]

    }

    getRandomX()
    getRandomY()
    moveGreenTile()

}
```

when the SpriteNode greenTile is tapped, getRandomY() getRandomX() and moveGreenTile() should be called.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set the `name` attribute of your `SKSpriteNodes`:

```
greenTile.name = "greenTile"
```

First I see some errors in your code. The return values of `getRandomX` and `getRandomY` never get really used. Because you set the `randomX` and `randomY` variables without actually calling `getRandom`. So you should update it to:

```
func moveGreenTile(){
    greenTile.position.x = greenTilePositionX[getRandomX()]
    greenTile.position.y = greenTilePositionY[getRandomY()]

}
```

That way you only have to call `moveGreenTile` and it will call the `getRandom` methods by itself.

Then you have to use the `touchesBegan` method to check if the user touches the screen. So with the name you can check if the user touched the `greenTile` by checking the name you've set earlier:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node:SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if(node.name == "greenTile"){
           moveGreenTile()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I added your code but it give the error "override can only be specified on class members" and the `moveGreenTile()` in the if statement give the error "cannot reference a local function with captures from another local function"

Comment: This answer seems to detect if a SKSpriteNode is touched, not tapped as the question requested?

Answer (score 0):

This code detects tap events, not only touches, on a SKSpriteNode.

You can change how sensitive the tap gesture is by modifying `TapMaxDelta`.

```
class TapNode : SKSpriteNode {

    // Tap Vars
    var firstPoint : CGPoint?
    var TapMaxDelta = CGFloat(10)


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Test.png")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }


    // ================================================================================================
    // Touch Functions
    // ================================================================================================
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let firstTouch = touches.first {
            firstPoint = firstTouch.location(in: self)
        }
    }


    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {}


    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let firstTouch = touches.first, let firstPoint = firstPoint {
            let curPoint = firstTouch.location(in: self)

            if abs(curPoint.x - firstPoint.x) <= TapMaxDelta && abs(curPoint.y - firstPoint.y) <= TapMaxDelta {
                print("tap yo")
            }
        }
    }
}
```